# multiple constraint keys

Tags: sql-server, compound-index

if i have tabled:

- Resource (id (PK), name)
- Manager (id(PK), resource_id (FK), manager_resource_ID(FK))

Should resource_id and manager_id both be foreign keys into the **Resource** table.

i obviously dont want to enter any values in each of those columns that are not proper resources

when i add the first relationship (resource_id <-> id) it works fine but

when i add the second one (manager_resource_id <-> id) it fails with the error:

**Unable to create relationship [ . . .]    The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint [... ]. The conflict occured in table Resource, column id**

or do i need to break this out into 3 tables?

Resource(id, first, last)
Resource_manager(id, resource_id, manager_ID)
Manager(id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint:

[image: resourcemngr_model_01]

**UPDATE**:

If your model has employee-manager as many-to-many (bit unusual) then you could do:

[image: resourcemngr_model_02]

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
  ( 
   EmployeeID int NOT NULL
  ,[Name] varchar(50)
  )
go  
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD
CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeID ASC)
go   

CREATE TABLE Manager
  ( 
   EmployeeID int NOT NULL
  ,ManagerID int NOT NULL
  )
go  
ALTER TABLE Manager ADD
 CONSTRAINT PK_Manager PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeID ASC, ManagerID ASC)
,CONSTRAINT FK1_Manager FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
,CONSTRAINT FK2_Manager FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
,CONSTRAINT chk_Manager CHECK (EmployeeID <> ManagerID) 
go
```

Comment: if i am foreign keying back to the same table for both the resource id and manager id do i really need 3 tables ?

Comment: `Resource` is for resources; `Employee` for employees, `ManagerID (BossID)` is for corporate hierarchy (who reports to whom). `ResourceManager` describes who is in charge of what -- I assume that resource is not an employee, but a thing or an "external object".

Comment: sorry  . . bad names perhaps . . i am using Resource as an employee table.  i dont want a resource to have a manager id as some resources have multiple managers (thus the initial 2 tables).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the foreign keys in the Manager table.

Comment: I was going to ask the author to post their code, but I think you're right about what their problem is.